# layout weight issuse for different screen

Tags: android, android-layout

I have two spinner and a square imageview . I have set the weight for fixing the layout so that in every screen the ratio is same in all screen like small,normal, large and xlarge. I have discarded the small. The image is given below :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hoNJj.jpg)

I have used the run time layout weight as like this :

```
private void initfixview()
{
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lnrspnrviewlayoutparams= (LinearLayout.LayoutParams)lnrspnrview.getLayoutParams();
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lnrimageviewlayoutparams= (LinearLayout.LayoutParams)lnrimageview.getLayoutParams();

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lnrdummyspacelayoutparams= (LinearLayout.LayoutParams)lnrdummyspace.getLayoutParams();
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lnrimgarrowupdownlayoutparams= (LinearLayout.LayoutParams)lnrimgarrowupdown.getLayoutParams();

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lnrcountrystatelayoutparams= (LinearLayout.LayoutParams)lnrcountrystate.getLayoutParams();
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lnrzipcodelayoutparams= (LinearLayout.LayoutParams)lnrzipcode.getLayoutParams();


    if ((getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE)
    {
        lnrspnrviewlayoutparams.weight=80;
        lnrspnrviewlayoutparams.width=80;


        lnrimageviewlayoutparams.weight=20;
        lnrimageviewlayoutparams.width=20;


        lnrspnrview.setLayoutParams(lnrspnrviewlayoutparams);
        lnrimageview.setLayoutParams(lnrimageviewlayoutparams);

        lnrdummyspacelayoutparams.weight=80;
        lnrdummyspacelayoutparams.width=80;


        lnrimgarrowupdownlayoutparams.weight=20;
        lnrimgarrowupdownlayoutparams.width=20;


        lnrdummyspace.setLayoutParams(lnrspnrviewlayoutparams);
        lnrimgarrowupdown.setLayoutParams(lnrimageviewlayoutparams);

        lnrcountrystatelayoutparams.weight=80;
        lnrcountrystatelayoutparams.width=80;


        lnrzipcodelayoutparams.weight=20;
        lnrzipcodelayoutparams.width=20;


        lnrcountrystate.setLayoutParams(lnrspnrviewlayoutparams);
        lnrzipcode.setLayoutParams(lnrimageviewlayoutparams);
    }
    else if ((getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_NORMAL)
    {
        lnrspnrviewlayoutparams.weight=70;
        lnrspnrviewlayoutparams.width=70;


        lnrimageviewlayoutparams.weight=30;
        lnrimageviewlayoutparams.width=30;


        lnrspnrview.setLayoutParams(lnrspnrviewlayoutparams);
        lnrimageview.setLayoutParams(lnrimageviewlayoutparams);

        lnrdummyspacelayoutparams.weight=70;
        lnrdummyspacelayoutparams.width=70;


        lnrimgarrowupdownlayoutparams.weight=30;
        lnrimgarrowupdownlayoutparams.width=30;


        lnrdummyspace.setLayoutParams(lnrspnrviewlayoutparams);
        lnrimgarrowupdown.setLayoutParams(lnrimageviewlayoutparams);


        lnrcountrystatelayoutparams.weight=70;
        lnrcountrystatelayoutparams.width=70;


        lnrzipcodelayoutparams.weight=30;
        lnrzipcodelayoutparams.width=30;


        lnrcountrystate.setLayoutParams(lnrspnrviewlayoutparams);
        lnrzipcode.setLayoutParams(lnrimageviewlayoutparams);
    }

    else if ((getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_XLARGE)
    {
        lnrspnrviewlayoutparams.weight=85;
        lnrspnrviewlayoutparams.width=85;


        lnrimageviewlayoutparams.weight=15;
        lnrimageviewlayoutparams.width=15;


        lnrspnrview.setLayoutParams(lnrspnrviewlayoutparams);
        lnrimageview.setLayoutParams(lnrimageviewlayoutparams);

        lnrdummyspacelayoutparams.weight=85;
        lnrdummyspacelayoutparams.width=85;


        lnrimgarrowupdownlayoutparams.weight=15;
        lnrimgarrowupdownlayoutparams.width=15;


        lnrdummyspace.setLayoutParams(lnrspnrviewlayoutparams);
        lnrimgarrowupdown.setLayoutParams(lnrimageviewlayoutparams);

        lnrcountrystatelayoutparams.weight=85;
        lnrcountrystatelayoutparams.width=85;


        lnrzipcodelayoutparams.weight=15;
        lnrzipcodelayoutparams.width=15;


        lnrcountrystate.setLayoutParams(lnrspnrviewlayoutparams);
        lnrzipcode.setLayoutParams(lnrimageviewlayoutparams);
    }

    else
    {
        lnrspnrviewlayoutparams.weight=70;
        lnrspnrviewlayoutparams.width=70;


        lnrimageviewlayoutparams.weight=30;
        lnrimageviewlayoutparams.width=30;


        lnrspnrview.setLayoutParams(lnrspnrviewlayoutparams);
        lnrimageview.setLayoutParams(lnrimageviewlayoutparams);

        lnrdummyspacelayoutparams.weight=70;
        lnrdummyspacelayoutparams.width=70;


        lnrimgarrowupdownlayoutparams.weight=30;
        lnrimgarrowupdownlayoutparams.width=30;


        lnrdummyspace.setLayoutParams(lnrspnrviewlayoutparams);
        lnrimgarrowupdown.setLayoutParams(lnrimageviewlayoutparams);

        lnrcountrystatelayoutparams.weight=70;
        lnrcountrystatelayoutparams.width=70;


        lnrzipcodelayoutparams.weight=30;
        lnrzipcodelayoutparams.width=30;


        lnrcountrystate.setLayoutParams(lnrspnrviewlayoutparams);
        lnrzipcode.setLayoutParams(lnrimageviewlayoutparams);
    }

    edtcompanyname.setHint(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.namecompany)));
    edtusertelephone.setHint(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.telephone)));
}
```

Now in devices its working fine but in some devices the ratio isnt maintained like normal devices with small size.

I have tried every possible solutions like smallest width, density factor and creating multiple layouts for the same:

The issued image is given below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LIAXG.png)

The code for my layout is given below:

```
<LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/pleaseselectonemarginstart"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/pleaseselectonemarginstart"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/pleaseselectonemarginstart"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/pleaseselectonemarginstart"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="100">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/lnrspnrview"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="70"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="center">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:background="@drawable/shadow_white_normal"
                        android:clickable="true"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">
                        <Spinner
                            android:id="@+id/spnrcountry"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:fontFamily="@font/sfdmedium"
                            android:gravity="center|left"
                            android:hint="@string/telephone"
                            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                            android:paddingStart="10dp"
                            android:textColor="@color/edtcolor"
                            android:textColorHint="@color/hintcolor"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/textsize" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/shadow_white_normal"
                        android:clickable="true"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <Spinner
                            android:id="@+id/spnrbusinesscategory"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:fontFamily="@font/sfdmedium"
                            android:gravity="center|left"
                            android:hint="@string/telephone"
                            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                            android:paddingStart="10dp"
                            android:textColor="@color/edtcolor"
                            android:textColorHint="@color/hintcolor"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/textsize" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/lnrimageview"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="30"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent">

                        <custom.SquareImageView
                            android:id="@+id/edtuploadimage"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:scaleType="fitXY"
                            android:src="@drawable/shadow_logo" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                            android:clickable="true"
                            android:fontFamily="@font/sfdmedium"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="@string/uploadlogo"
                            android:textColor="@color/hintcolor"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/lessertextsize" />
                    </RelativeLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
```

I will be very glad here any possible solution. As I have every solution to this problem from creating multiple layout and smallest width and others.

Comment: use [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/) insted.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the weight in xml you don't need to change at run time based on device screen, it will preserve the same ratio for all screens. I have made some correction to you layout:

```
<LinearLayout 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal">
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/lnrspnrview"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="6"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spnrcountry"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spnrbusinesscategory"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="4">

    <custom.SquareImageView
        android:id="@+id/edtuploadimage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:gravity="center" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here i just give the hint how the structure of your layout should've look like. If you follow this, then you do not need to change the weight programatically based on device screen because it will be same for all.